# flask with docker returning 404 on all routes except root

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have been investigating related questions but could not find a correct solution to this issue. All of my routes work locally. However, when I run `docker-compose up` to containerize my app, my app will start but all routes except for the root "hello world" route returns a 404 error.

I've attempted setting "SERVER_NAME" in `app.config` and appending an extra "/" on my route urls like other posts have suggested but to no avail.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

app/app.py

```
@app.route("/")                        # <-- this route works
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, world!"

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])  # <-- this one doesn't
def test():
    return "Test POST route"

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6

COPY requirements.txt /

WORKDIR /

RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

COPY app/ /app/

WORKDIR /app

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_ENV=production
CMD flask db upgrade && python app.py
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
env_file:
 - .env
```

Comment: I notice that you have an extra "." in the host. It should be `host="0.0.0.0"`, not sure if that causes any issues.

Comment: Edited. This was a typo but it does not solve the error.

Comment: How did you verify that /test route did not work? Could you provide Docker logs?

Comment: Make sure that you send POST request to verify that your /test route works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the source code folder in the docker compose rather than the dockerfile, otherwise you need to rebuild the image every time the code changes. In docker compose you can use volumes property to do this. You can read more here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Example

```
version: '3'
services:
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
env_file:
 - .env
volumes:
 - ./app:/app
```

Comment: Mounting source code will not resolve the problem and completely unrelated.

Comment: If the image was build when the code was only hello world, then the docker will only respond to that, as well as all other further changes of the code will not be reflected in the image.

Comment: Did not even think about it but could be possible.